# not able to select dynamic dropdown in spice jet site by using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

not able to select dynamic dropdown in spice jet site by using selenium webdriver.Please look into this. below is my code:

```
driver.get("http://www.spicejet.com/");
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ctl00_mainContent_ddl_originStation1_CTXT']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@value='GOI']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ctl00_mainContent_ddl_destinationStation1_CTXT']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='dropdownDiv']/ul/li[4]")).click();
```

Comment: add Thread.sleep(1000) or use webdriver to make your script to wait till the dropdowns are displayed based on your selection.

Comment: In general, `Thread.sleep()` is bad practice. If you need to wait, use `WebDriverWait`. See my answer below for working code.

Answer (score 1):

Please add a visibility wait before selection of dropwdown.

**like**

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("test")));
new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("test"))).selectByVisibleText("test77");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your last XPath I think was incorrect. It was pointing to a panel that was not open at the time. I would do something like this. This is working code.

```
driver.get("http://www.spicejet.com/");
setOriginStation("GOI");
setDestinationStation("BOM");
```

and use these functions to handle selections for origin and destination stations.

```
public static void setOriginStation(String station)
{
    driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_mainContent_ddl_originStation1_CTXT")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#glsctl00_mainContent_ddl_originStation1_CTNR a[value='" + station + "']")).click();
}

public static void setDestinationStation(String station)
{
    driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_mainContent_ddl_destinationStation1_CTXT")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#glsctl00_mainContent_ddl_destinationStation1_CTNR a[value='" + station + "']")).click();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code.
Actually from city and destination city have same drop-down component means both drop-down are same. So, in second selection, City value will xpath will be counted twice.So select [2]. [2] doesn't work for me so tried with [1]

driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#ctl00_mainContent_ddl_originStation1_CTXT")).click();

```
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@value='GOI']")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//a[@value='DEL'])[1]")).click();
```